# How to split line of texts(two or more (using end by dot in the same line)) and view as a list item in template laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have saved a couple of lines in the database. 
For example:

```
    Material.php // Model Name 
    id | materials
    1  | i have a book.
         i have a pen.
```

How to show these two lines of materials column into the blade template with list view using laravel 4.2.

I want to show these two lines of columns(the columns are text valued) lines like:

```
 . i have a book.
 . i have a pen.
```

Materials.php // Controllers File

```
    public function getMaterials($id){
        $m = Material::find($id);

        echo "<li>";
        echo $m;
        echo "</li>";
    }
```

I tried in the controllers to check the output format but failed. So how to show in the list format? Plz help.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: public function materials()
          {
  $m= Material::all();
  
  $str = $m->materials;
  $arr = explode("", $str); 
  
  echo "<li>";
  echo $str;
  echo "</li>";
             }


i try to check as i dont know how to split thats why i need help. i use explode but it does not work.

Comment: Edit your question and put the code there, it's unreadable in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

public function getMaterials($id){

```
    $m = Material::find($id);
    $explode = explode('.', $m->materials);
    echo "<li>". $explode[0].".</li>";
    echo "<li>". $explode[1].".</li>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, I haven't used Laravel 4.2, but I would assume something like this would work in the view:

```
<ul>
@foreach(preg_split('/\.\s*$/', $material->materials) as $material_part)
    <li>{{ $material_part }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```